# Почему на iPhone 6 размытая фоновая картинка?

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте! Почему iPhone 6 фоновая картинка в первом экране, на главной странице, размытая. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая может быть причина этого? http://www.matchpoint-club.com

нашел причину, дело было не в качестве картинки, я делал параллакс в первом экране и для фоновой картинки задал fixed, так как это для параллакса нужно. Когда убрал это свойство, то картинка стала нормальной. Но без fixed для фона, параллакс не будет нормально работать)

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что все дело в Retina-дисплеях. https://habrahabr.ru/post/150071/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайти об современных ретиновых экран iphone и как решить это. Гугл ответит. Обычно две фотки делают один для ретин а второй для простых соответсвенно один большой второй нет

Вобщем причина в экране ретиновым почитай побольше об этом

Comment: нашел причину, дело было не в качестве картинки, я делал параллакс в первом экране и для фоновой картинки задал fixed, так как это для параллакса нужно. Когда убрал это свойство, то картинка стала нормальной